# After added SubscribeOn and ObserveOn in stream method chaining not getting trigger

Tags: java, rx-java3

I am using `rxjava3` and not quite understanding why method are not getting called in stream after added `ObserveOn` and `SubscribeOn`.

Here is the example java code:

```
package mytestapp.error;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.annotations.NonNull;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        String apiUrl = "myApiUrl";
        try {
            App app = new App();
            app.syncNow(apiUrl);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void syncNow(String apiUrl) throws JSONException, IOException {
        createOrAlterTable().observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .switchMap(d -> menuTableRecords(apiUrl))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(res -> {
                    System.out.println(res);

                }, onError -> {
                    System.out.println(onError);
                }, () -> {
                    System.out.println("Completed!!");
                });
        ;
    }

    private @NonNull Observable<Object> createOrAlterTable()
            throws IOException, JSONException {
        // Read table from backend
        // Read last sync file
        // get user data
        return Observable.zip(readTableFromBackend(), readLastSyncFile(),
                getUserData(),
                (s1, s2, s3) -> readTableFromBackendZipperFun(s1, s2, s3)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(
                d -> d);
    }

    private @NonNull Observable<String> readTableFromBackend()
            throws JSONException, IOException {
        return Observable.fromArray("testing");
    }

    private @NonNull Observable<JSONObject> readLastSyncFile()
            throws JSONException {
        return Observable.fromArray(new JSONObject());
    }

    private @NonNull Observable<Boolean> getUserData() throws JSONException {
        return Observable.fromArray(true);
    }

    private JSONArray readTableFromBackendZipperFun(String sqlliteDDL,
            JSONObject lastFV, boolean userDataFlag) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println("zip ops");
        return new JSONArray();
    }

    private @NonNull Observable<String> menuTableRecords(String apiUrl)
            throws JSONException, IOException {
        
        return Observable.fromArray("MENU_TABLE_RECORDS");
    }
}
```

I want to execute each method on separate thread and on subscription also on different thread.

what is the cause making problem .how to solve above case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't wait for the async activity to finish in the `main` method and your application just quits. Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation

You can workaround the problem by using `blockingSubscribe` instead of just `subscribe` in this particular case.